# What is the use case for flatMap vs map in kotlin

Tags: collections, kotlin, flatmap

in https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Kotlin%20Koans/Collections/FlatMap/Task.kt

it has sample of using `flatMap` and `map`

seems both are doing the same thing, is there a sample to show the difference of using `flatMap` and `map`?

the data type:

```
data class Shop(val name: String, val customers: List<Customer>)

data class Customer(val name: String, val city: City, val orders: List<Order>) {
    override fun toString() = "$name from ${city.name}"
}

data class Order(val products: List<Product>, val isDelivered: Boolean)

data class Product(val name: String, val price: Double) {
    override fun toString() = "'$name' for $price"
}

data class City(val name: String) {
    override fun toString() = name
}
```

the samples:

```
fun Shop.getCitiesCustomersAreFrom(): Set<City> =
    customers.map { it.city }.toSet()
    // would it be same with customers.flatMap { it.city }.toSet() ?

val Customer.orderedProducts: Set<Product> get() {
    return orders.flatMap { it.products }.toSet()
    // would it be same with return orders.map { it.products }.toSet()
}
```

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Consider the following example: You have a simple data structure `Data` with a single property of type `List`.

```
class Data(val items : List<String>)

val dataObjects = listOf(
    Data(listOf("a", "b", "c")), 
    Data(listOf("1", "2", "3"))
)
```

**`flatMap` vs. `map`**

With `flatMap`, you can "flatten" multiple `Data::items` into one collection as shown with the `items` variable.

```
val items: List<String> = dataObjects
    .flatMap { it.items } //[a, b, c, 1, 2, 3]
```

Using `map`, on the other hand, simply results in a list of lists.

```
val items2: List<List<String>> = dataObjects
    .map { it.items } //[[a, b, c], [1, 2, 3]]
```

**`flatten`**

There's also a `flatten` extension on `Iterable<Iterable<T>>` and also `Array<Array<T>>` which you can use alternatively to `flatMap` when using those types:

```
val nestedCollections: List<Int> = 
    listOf(listOf(1,2,3), listOf(5,4,3))
        .flatten() //[1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3]
```

Comment: What is the use of `flatten` vs `flatMap`?

Comment: `flatMap(function)` is the same as `map(function).flatten()`

Comment: @ScottDriggers I think you meant `.flatten().map(function)`?

Answer (score 67):

There are three functions in play here. **map()**, **flatten()**, and **flatMap()** which is a combination of the first two.

#### Consider the following example

```kotlin
data class Hero (val name:String)
data class Universe (val heroes: List<Hero>)
    
val batman = Hero("Bruce Wayne")
val wonderWoman = Hero (name = "Diana Prince")
    
val mailMan = Hero("Stan Lee")
val deadPool = Hero("Wade Winston Wilson")
    
val marvel = Universe(listOf(mailMan, deadPool))
val dc = Universe(listOf(batman, wonderWoman))
    
val allHeroes: List<Universe> = listOf(marvel, dc)
```

#### Map

```kotlin
allHeroes.map { it.heroes }
```

```
// output: [[Hero(name=Stan Lee), Hero(name=Wade Winston Wilson)], [Hero(name=Bruce Wayne), Hero(name=Diana Prince)]]
```

Map allows you to access each universe in {allHeroes} and (in this case) return
its list of heroes. So the output will be a list containing two lists of heroes,
one for each universe.
The result is a List<List>

#### Flatmap

```kotlin
allHeroes.flatMap { it.heroes }
```

```
// output: [Hero(name=Stan Lee), Hero(name=Wade Winston Wilson), Hero(name=Bruce Wayne), Hero(name=Diana Prince)]
```

FlatMap allows you to do the same as map, access the two lists of heroes from
both universes. But it goes further and flattens the returned list of lists
into a single list.
The result is a List

#### Flatten

```kotlin
allHeroes.map { it.heroes }.flatten()
```

```
// output: [Hero(name=Stan Lee), Hero(name=Wade Winston Wilson), Hero(name=Bruce Wayne), Hero(name=Diana Prince)]
```

This produces the same result as flatMap.
So flatMap is a combination of the two functions, map{} and then flatten()

Comment: Is there any performance difference between .map{ f }.flatten() vs .flatMap{ f } ?

Comment: cmiiw

the former: O(2n) time complexity (doing the first n on `.map` then `.flatten`)
the latter: O(n) time complexity @KristopherNoronha

Comment: @mochadwi I think O notation ignores the constant, so both are O(n) as far as time is concerned... however I suspect memory/temp objects might paint a different story and that's probably the diffrentiating factor when working with large structures.

Comment: agreed, the actual differentiation factor was the space constraint

Answer (score 0):

- **Map** is used to transform a list based on certain conditions(Map helps us to perform a certain transformation to each and every element of the list and it returns a list of newly transformed data).
- **FlatMap** is used to combine all the items of lists into one list(FlatMap is used to combine two different collections and returns as a single collection).

for more detail refer to [FlatMap vs Map in Kotlin](https://blog.mindorks.com/flatmap-vs-map-in-kotlin)